# Micronaut configuration property default value

Tags: micronaut

I am not sure this is a bug. As a matter of facts this may be the expected behavior.

Assume I have the following configuration class

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    public String uri = "/api/v1";

    // I also tested with optional, no difference
    // public Optional<String> uri = Optional.of("/api/v1");
}
```

and I use the annotation `@Controller("${app.uri}/some/path")` on a controller.

If I do not add an entry in `application.yml` then I end up with the following error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder ${app.uri} in value: ${app.uri}/some/path
```

While if I add the following lines to my `application.yml`

```
app:
  uri: /api/v2
```

Then every thing works: the placeholder is resolved to `/api/v2` and also the value in the injectable configuration object is set to `/api/v2` instead of the default value `/api/v1`.

I would have expected that if I do not set a value in `application.yml` the default value in the class would have been resolved (`/api/v1`).

Again this may be just by design, and it is fine. I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong and, in this case, how to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. It's not feasible to know if a property has a default value in a configuration class. To supply the default value in that context, simply do:

`@Controller("${app.uri:/api/v1}/some/path")`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I will probably stick with not setting a default value at this point and just add it as a required prop.

Answer (score 0):

Micronaut is very annotation based, so you can simply include annotation

```
@Nullable
```

Along with your @Property annotation to prevent compilation error.

Also in your configuration class you do something like :

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Nullable
    public String uri = "/api/v1";

    public String getUri() {
         return uril?: "/api/v1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope this is not working unfortunately. And looking at the code it makes sense that this approach should not be different from what I posted. Thanks for proposing it though!

Comment: Nullable annotation works, I am using it in my code, although I have not used it with ConfigurationProperties annotation, I directly use Property annotation to invoke configurations and sometimes add Nullable to mark properties optional.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the latest documentation for [micronaut configuration](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/config.html#configurationProperties), the following should work.

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.ConfigurationProperties
import javax.validation.constraints.Min import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank

@ConfigurationProperties('my.engine')
class EngineConfig {

    @NotBlank
    String manufacturer = "Ford"

    @Min(1L)
    int cylinders
    CrankShaft crankShaft = new CrankShaft()

    @ConfigurationProperties('crank-shaft')
    static class CrankShaft {
        Optional<Double> rodLength = Optional.empty()
    }

}
```